# Why does the first load of my site take so long?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I am using Rails 3.2.x and Thin 1.5.0 and when initially loading my app, after not loading it for say 24 hours, it takes VERY long. At first I thought it was just my macbook - because it was in sleep mode and the first time it was just taking forever for whatever reason.

But, I realized that it does the same on Heroku and it also does the same for other people. Like when they haven't visited the Heroku site for a while, the first time they load it (not EVERY single time, but some times) it takes FOREVER.

According to the log, it seems that the compilation of my stylesheets take forever. What I am confused about though, is when I push to Heroku it should compile the assets during the push...right? So, in theory, that shouldn't be what is slowing it down in production. Or am I missing something?

Although, in recent times, Heroku has been rejecting pushes so I have had to enable this:

```
# Don't initialize app on pre-compile
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

So I am not sure if that is what is contributing to it.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-19 02:44:14 -0500
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Category Load (56.6ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" LIMIT 6
  EXPLAIN (14.6ms)  EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" LIMIT 6
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  LIMIT 6
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE categories (~1000000 rows)

  Banner Load (44.4ms)  SELECT "banners".* FROM "banners" INNER JOIN "banner_types" ON "banner_types"."id" = "banners"."banner_type_id" WHERE (banner_types.name = 'Featured')
  Banner Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "banners".* FROM "banners" INNER JOIN "banner_types" ON "banner_types"."id" = "banners"."banner_type_id" WHERE (banner_types.name = 'Side')
  Product Load (3.4ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" 
  Vendor Load (15.9ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" 
  User Load (50.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  EXPLAIN (0.1ms)  EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE users (~1000000 rows)

  Vendor Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 12 LIMIT 1
  Vendor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 11 LIMIT 1
  Vendor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 10 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 12 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 12 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 10 LIMIT 1
  Rendered home/_popular_products.html.erb (303.0ms)
  Rendered home/_popular_stores.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (570.6ms)
Compiled main.css  (20360ms)  (pid 86898)
Compiled application.css  (2366ms)  (pid 86898)
  Rendered layouts/_login_nav.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (47.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 38402ms (Views: 30707.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1830.8ms)
```

Thoughts?

**Edit 1:**

Please note that this question hasn't been adequately answered. The responses both talk about the issue on Heroku - which is part of the question. However, they fail to address this issue happening in development.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku will spin down your app to save resources, if it's not accessed for a certain amount of time. Thus the slowness is caused by having to start up the entire app again.

See Dyno Idling on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos for more information.

To get around this, you can use services such as the New Relic addon, that will ping your app every so often, to stop the spin down.

You also should be compiling your assets on deploy, not on demand. Heroku should do this by default - what did you change to stop it happening?

Comment: Those logs are for my dev environment - not Heroku. The only change I have made to asset compilation is in my `config/application.rb` I set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` as I stated in the question.

Comment: Also.....this makes sense....but it doesn't fully explain why the first request locally also takes forever. i.e. in development, why when I wake my machine out of sleep does the first request take so long? Should I quit the Terminal session with Thin running and restart my server once I wake my macbook from sleep or is there something else happening?

Comment: Once I install New Relic, do I have to configure it specifically to tell it to ping my app every hour? Or once I install it, it does that automagically?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 1 dyno on Heroku (free plan) then it will go idle after a while to save resources. Then when someone accesses your app after a while it will start up again.

So the first person to access your app will have to wait for a while.

Comment: Ahh....right. But what about in development? That's what those logs are for....my dev environ.